# Trace of the square of the metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with Ricci curvature $R_{ij}$. After using some conditions, I have the following equation
$$R_{ij}=\lambda g^2_{ij},$$
where $g^2_{ij}=g(\partial_i,\partial_j)g(\partial_i,\partial_j)$ is the square of the coefficient of the metric tensor $g$. Now if I take trace in both sides of the above equation, the right hand side becomes scalar curvature but I am not able to find trace of the left hand side. I suppose that it will be $n$ (the dimension of the manifold) but don't have enough confidence.
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand your notations correctly, $(g^2)_{ij}=g_{ik}g_{lj}g^{kl}$ (summation over repeated indices is implied). In this case $(g^2)_i^i=(g^2)_{ij}g^{ij}=g_{ik}g_{lj}g^{kl}g^{ij}=\delta_i^l\delta_l^i=\delta_i^i=n$ and $R=n\lambda$

Comment: The right side has to be a tensor. So Syvatoslav’s interpretation is the most reasonable one.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: So what @Svyatoslav has suggested is very different from what you wrote in your question. Are you agreeing that you meant to have what he said? You specifically said "the square of the coefficient of the metric tensor," and, as Deane said, that can't make sense.

Comment: The right side of my equation is a 2-tensor. I think the square of the coefficient of the metric tensor is same as what @Svyatoslav has suggested. Am I not correct?

Comment: No. How do you think $g_{ij}^2$ defines a tensor?

Comment: @Svyatoslav: Your interpretation is if $$A=\begin{pmatrix} x& y\\y&z\end{pmatrix}$$ then $$A^2_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix} x^2+y^2& y(x+z)\\y(x+z)&y^2+z^2\end{pmatrix}_{ij}?$$ Yeah?

Comment: @C.F.G. I'm afraid not. My interpretation is that we keep the tensor structure on both sides, and $(g^2)_{ij}=g_{ik}g_{lj}g^{kl}=g_{lj}$. If $Ag_{ik}=\begin{pmatrix} x& y\\y&z\end{pmatrix}$, $g^{kl}=A^{-1}$. If we have two tensors $A$ and $B$ and want to keep the covariant (tensor) structure of the equation, we should understand $(AB)_{im}$ as $ A_{ik}g^{kl}B_{lm}$. I admit that another meaning could be in  $(g^2)_{ik}$, but it should be specified.

Comment: @Svyatoslav: my interpretation is this: $\mathrm{Ric}=\lambda h$ where $h=g^2_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$. Is this same as yours?

Comment: @C.F.G. How do you define $g^2_{ik}$ - do you understand $g^2_{il}$ as $g_{ik}g_{kl}$ or as $g_{ik}g^{kj}g_{jl}$ (summation over repeated indices is implied)?

Comment: @Svyatoslav: I think the OP and me meant $g^2_{ij}=g_{ij}\times g_{ij}$ and not of yours.

Comment: @C.F.G. you you meant $A^2_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix} x^2+y^2& y(x+z)\\y(x+z)&y^2+z^2\end{pmatrix}_{ij}$ - it means $A_{ik}A_{jk}$ (or $A_{ik}A_{kj}$ - because $A_{ij}$ is symmetric). This is of course not my meaning and my solution is not valid. But your expression is not covariant in general sense and, generally speaking, not a tensor.

Comment: @Svyatoslav: In that comment i asked you that "is that matrix as yours". But my interpretation is the my last comment. i.e. $g^2_{ij}=g_{ij}\times g_{ij}$. (note that no sum assumed here)

Comment: C.F.G. I'm sorry I don't understand your notation $g^2_{ij}=g_{ij}\times g_{ij}$ - you have two different indices in the LHS and a couple of repeated indices in the RHS. If you have $g_{ik}=A_{ik}=A=\begin{pmatrix} x& y\\y&z\end{pmatrix}$, how do you define $A^2_{ij}$? If $A^2_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix} x^2+y^2& y(x+z)\\y(x+z)&y^2+z^2\end{pmatrix}_{ij}$ - please look at my previous comment.

Comment: @Svyatoslav: I meant ${A_{ij}}^2$ not ${A^2}_{ij}$. i.e. $${A_{ij}}^2=\begin{pmatrix} x^2 & y^2\\y^2& z^2\end{pmatrix}_{ij}$$

Comment: @C.F.G. I see. But in this case my solution is not applicable -  ${A_{ij}}^2=\begin{pmatrix} x^2 & y^2\\y^2& z^2\end{pmatrix}_{ij}$ is not a covariant tensor.

Comment: @Svyatoslav: Anyway, I think the OP meant this tensor.  as s/he indicated $g^2_{ij}=g(\partial_i,\partial_j)g(\partial_i,\partial_j)$ that there is no sum here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comments mislead the OP. In my opinion the only way to make it meaningful is that by $\mathrm{R}_{ij}=\lambda g^2_{ij}$ you probably meant $\mathrm{Ric}=\lambda h$ where $h=(g_{ij})^2dx^i\otimes dx^j$ i.e., $h_{ij}=(g_{ij})^2=g_{ij}\times g_{ij}$ (no sum assumed).
In this case its trace is $=\sum_{i}{(g_{ii})^2}=(g_{11})^2+(g_{22})^2+\dots+(g_{nn})^2$ which cannot be simplified further or rewrite it using $tr(g)$.

**NOTE:** In comments some commenters thought that $g_{ij}^2=(g^2)_{ij}$ and some others considered it as $S=g_{ij}g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes dx^i\otimes dx^j=g_{11}^2dx^1\otimes dx^1\otimes dx^1\otimes dx^1+g_{12}^2dx^1\otimes dx^2\otimes dx^1\otimes dx^2+\dots$ which is not a tensor if one consider it as rank 2-tensor wrongly i.e. $S(X,Y)=g(X,Y)g(X,Y)$.